# Junk character when using System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding.GetString

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I am extracting string from an byte array. The string is a sql script.

```
String sql = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1200).GetString(script);
```

The first character is coming out to be junk(square box in preview). Due to which the whole script is failing. Any idea why this is happening?

I don't want to specifically remove the first character. More interested in knowing why and how can this be avoided.

Comment: There is no difference between `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding` and `System.Text.UTF32Encoding.GetEncoding`. I've removed the reference to `UTF32Encoding` because it might confuse people.

Comment: Do you have the actual sequence of bytes?

Comment: @lganacio: Actual sequence? 'script' is a byte array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first character(s) are probably [Byte Order Marks (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

You can use a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bc2hwcb.aspx) to automatically detect any BOM and select the appropriate encoding:

```
byte[] script;
string sql;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(script), true))
{                                   //                          ↑ 
    sql = reader.ReadToEnd();       //        detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks
}
```